# Crash after trying JSON serialization

Tags: swift

I have this simple code:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

                    print(response)

                    do {
                        let JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                        // never printed                    
                        print(JSON)

                        guard let JSONDictionary :NSDictionary = (JSON as! NSDictionary) else {
                            print("Not a Dictionary")

                            return
                        }

                        print("JSONDictionary! \(JSONDictionary)")

                    }
                    catch let JSONError as NSError {

                        print("\(JSONError)")
                    }

                });

                //
                task.resume()
```

Well, I can read the response but then I get `(lldb)` and the app crashes. The line `print(JSON)` is never printed. I really can't understand what's going on, any tip is appreciated.

Comment: I think your data may be nil.

Comment: Tips: do not force unwrap unless 1000% sure the optional is NEVER EVER nil + debug via breakpoints or at least via print-statement of pretty much everything that is going on in your code.

Comment: @thefredelement: I can actually see the data, I can read the response and it is too large not to contain data

Comment: BTW `print("\(JSONError)")` is silly (but probably harmless): you can just say `print(JSONError)`

Comment: What if you replace `.AllowFragments` with `[]` - does that solve it?

Comment: But why you deleted your post? (anyway, the line was the one I was talking about, that is something happens during the serialization)

Comment: Oh, no, I tried ANY of the possibilities for the options, it always crashes

Comment: Can you tell me the URL? I'd like to try it myself.

Comment: Ok, maybe I understand now: they really return an invalid JSON, even if the header is correctly reporting application/json. I suppose (not sure) before parsing I should treat the result as a String and remove the wrong data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is not JSON, it's JSONP (JSON with Padding). ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP))

`NSJSONSerialization` cannot serialize JSONP.

Since `try` has failed, `print(JSON)` won't execute, and the code jumps to the `catch` block.

Comment: I must say two things: the server is incredibly slow (so initially I thought there could be a timeout issue). The second is I receive that data as application/json, whose mime should be, if I'm not wrong, application/javascript

Comment: Look at your data carefully, it starts with `jsonp1458829826648({"LeSolu...`. That is not valid JSON, which must start with `{` or `[`.

Comment: I noticed it. Anyway, would it be a good idea to treat the result as a regular string, trimming the unnecessary parts and parsing the remaining string as JSON?

Comment: Yes, trimming will work since JSONP without Padding is JSON. Search for the first `(` and the last `)`, trim everything outside and including those parentheses and you have your JSON data.

Comment: Also, if you remove the `&jsoncallback=` field from your request URL, you only need to remove the parentheses (smaller payload too). Then you only need to check if the first and last byte is `(` and `)`, which you should do in case the server is fixed to send valid JSON in the future.